# accessing JSON PHP array issue

Tags: php, json

Hi I have this JSON response and I wanted to access the images of each pages, how would I access these images when the id of each page is unknown(generated randomly)?

```
string(310) "{"query":{"redirects":[{"from":"Romerolagus diazi",
                                       "to":"Volcano rabbit"}],
       "pages":{"4733563":
          {"pageid":4733563,
           "ns":0,
           "title":"Volcano rabbit",
           "images":[
              {"ns":6,"title":"File:Question book-new.svg"},
              {"ns":6,"title":"File:Romerolagus diazi (dispale) 001.jpg"},
              {"ns":6,"title":"File:Status iucn2.3 EN.svg"}
                    ]
           }}}}"
```

My attempt:

```
$result = $json->pages[0];
echo "{$result->images}";
```

Comment: What did your attempt produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. This is working

```
CODE SAMPLE ONE : 
    $var = json_decode('{"query":{"redirects":[{"from":"Romerolagus diazi","to":"Volcano rabbit"}],"pages":{"4733563":{"pageid":4733563,"ns":0,"title":"Volcano rabbit","images":[{"ns":6,"title":"File:Question book-new.svg"},{"ns":6,"title":"File:Romerolagus diazi (dispale) 001.jpg"},{"ns":6,"title":"File:Status iucn2.3 EN.svg"}]}}}} ');
    echo "<pre>"; 
    foreach($var->query->pages as $da) 
    {
    $image_array= $da->images;  
    $i=0; 
    foreach($image_array as $img)
    {$i++;
    echo "<Br/> ".$i.")".$images = $img->title;     

    }

    }




OR

 CODE SAMPLE TWO :


$var = json_decode('{"query":{"redirects":[{"from":"Romerolagus diazi","to":"Volcano rabbit"}],"pages":{"4733563":{"pageid":4733563,"ns":0,"title":"Volcano rabbit","images":[{"ns":6,"title":"File:Question book-new.svg"},{"ns":6,"title":"File:Romerolagus diazi (dispale) 001.jpg"},{"ns":6,"title":"File:Status iucn2.3 EN.svg"}]}}}} ',true);
echo "<pre>";

foreach($var['query']['pages'] as $da) 
{
$image_array= $da['images'];    
$i=0; 
foreach($image_array as $img)
{$i++;
echo "<Br/> ".$i.")".$images = $img['title'];   

}

}

Output : 


 1)File:Question book-new.svg
 2)File:Romerolagus diazi (dispale) 001.jpg
 3)File:Status iucn2.3 EN.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an invalid element. Try the following instead:

```
echo $json->query->pages->{4733563}->images[1]->title;
```

Output:

```
File:Romerolagus diazi (dispale) 001.jpg
```

**[Demo 1!](http://codepad.org/96rCBeSV)**

---

Alternatively, you could set the second parameter in [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to `TRUE` if you want an associative array instead:

```
$string = '...';
$json = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($json['query']['pages']['4733563']['images'][0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ns] => 6
    [title] => File:Question book-new.svg
)
```

**[Demo 2!](http://codepad.org/yfnl5H0p)**